# Sharepoint 2013-Managing folders

Tags: document-library

Is there a way to manage folders in SP2013 as opposed to the documents within the folders. I have a library setup that uses folders to house multiple documents. I want to be able to change the status of the folder to expired and move that folder and all the documents within to an archive library (still keeping it in that folder). Is there a way to do this, or a better way?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Explorer view to manually [copy/delete/paste](https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-to-copy-and-move-files-between-sharepoint-document-libraries-and-folders.html) Folders between two libraries

If you looking for automated process then you can use

1. Scheduled PowerShell Script
2. Timer Job

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to explore the use of document sets. A document set is a special type of folder in SharePoint that supports tagging with metadata.

- In addition to supporting metadata, document sets also introduce some handy features for versioning and running workflows against the entire set.
- You can set columns to be shared between the document set and the documents within the set, so that changing a field on the document set changes it for all documents within the set.
- You can also have document sets be automatically provisioned with document templates upon creation, which is handy if a document set represents a project or portfolio that has certain pre-defined documents required.
- Finally, you can define a "welcome page" for a document set, allowing you to customize what information is displayed when someone is looking inside the document set.

For more information, refer to Microsoft's documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637(v=office.15).aspx